# Column with DateTime value in WPFToolkit DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to make a simple DateTime column, for setting Time values. Playing around like that:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Start" Binding="{Binding Path=StartAt, StringFormat=0:hh:mm:ss tt}"/>
```

it appears normal but changing the value doesn't work out. I dunno why. 
And is there any possibility to make some kind of "mask", which helps to enter values? I mean skipping colons, taking only digits and etc.
Obviously there is some potential of WPF to make controls like DateTimePicker, but not for Dates, but just Time values.

Could you guys show me an example please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following formatting works for me:

```
Binding="{Binding StartAt, StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm:ss}'}"
```